# How to find vertex mapping on a topologically symmetrical mesh?

Tags: graphics, 3d

I have a human head mesh that is topologically symmetrical but the mesh shape is not. When I choose a vertex on the mesh(for example, a vertex on the left face), how can I find the topologically symmetrical vertex(the corresponding vertex on the right face) ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've done this and it kind of depends: Do you need it to run very very fast, user interactively only, or can it be slow as with an offline utility? Do you need to do this just for one or two head meshes or dozens/hundreds? Does it need to map perfectly every time, or can it accommodate being close with a little human help here and there? Does the head geo you input need to be any unstructured poly-soup mesh, or can it be divided into two topologically mirrored but geometrically asymmetrical halves? I'd need a little more background about the context of your problem to give useful direction.